# "Are to" and "Have to"

Tags: grammar, be, have

There's a question in an exam paper to which there's only one answer:

> Students ______ to make tough decisions after the final exams are out.
>
> Between 'have' and 'are', which most suitably fills the gap?

(the tense of the passage is present - from a newspaper actually)

Comment: Exam-related questions are highly discouraged on English Stack Exchange. Please consider moving this post to [ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Note the phrase "most suitably." See [writers.se]

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/613772/2085).

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in the words "*there's only one answer*". Professor Pullum, co-author of *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*, has written of the problematic nature of exam questions which require a binary choice. [See below.]

In the present case, both answers are grammatical, although one is more probable than the other.

The construction "*are to*" has various possible uses. Swan in *Practical English Usage* (p80) lists 6 of these. Among them:

> Usage 1: We use this structure in a formal style to talk about
>   official and other plans and arrangements.
>
> - The President is to visit Nigeria next month.
> - We are to get a 10 per cent wage rise in June. ...
>
> Usage 5: The structure is used to give orders, often by parents speaking to children.
>
> - You are to do your homework before watching TV. ...

Both of the above uses are conceivable in the present context. Much more likely, however, is the use of *have to* to express a necessity, equivalent to:

> Students will need to make tough decisions after the final exams are
>   out.

---

Pullum in *[Correct/Incorrect Grammar-Test Items](https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2016/04/18/correctincorrect-grammar-test-items)*

> I wish people would avoid using this sort of differential preference
>   in grammar-test items, testing for knowledge of a fictive
>   grammaticality distinction. If “Correct/Incorrect” test items are to
>   be used, the “Incorrect” choice better be genuinely incorrect.

See also Pullum in *[Grammar-Test Dispute Resolution](https://www.chronicle.com/blogs/linguafranca/2016/05/08/grammar-test-dispute-resolution/)*.

Comment: It's not a grammar question, as you've already noted. Please see also my comment at OP.

Comment: @Kris. Maybe the OP can tell us more about the test. But grammar or not, it is a a decontextualised binary choice question, and I thought site visitors might be interested in Pullum's view about such questions. As to where the question belongs (ELU, ELL, or Writing), I genuinely don't know.